# Possible worlds/beliefs/Probability Matrix/Example 3

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, matrix-equations, game-theory

I the snippet below, copied from the Handbook of Game Theory with Economic Applications, the condition (2.1) says that we can rearrange the **columns**
so that the matrix becomes **block** diagonal with each block having the same rows. My question is, is this rearrangement **unique** in the sense that it yields the same subset of the heading of the matrix, which is in the example 3 $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ in each block? OR on the contrary can we end up
with different subsets in some block?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$  cannot be reordered as a [block diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) and is a suitable belief matrix.

But if a matrix can be reordered as a block matrix with only column operations, then such reorder is unique: let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be the basis for the domain, $w_1, \ldots, w_k$ the basis of the codomain that makes $A$ a block matrix. Then you will have $$\text{span}(Av_1, \ldots,Av_{i_1}) \ \subseteq\text{span}(w_1, \ldots, w_{j_1}), \ \text{span}(Av_{i_{1}+1}, \ldots,Av_{i_2}) \ \subseteq\text{span}(w_{j_1+1}, \ldots, w_{j_2}), \ldots$$ and so on. Reordering the columns you are only changing the order of the vectors in the basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, and you can easily see that this identify the blocks (besides permutations inside the block).